# Comparing and matching to python lists

Tags: python, list

Let's say that I had a pattern list and a list of strings (equal length). By comparing the positions of each string in the list of strings with the patterns in the pattern list, i need to return a list of lists with all the strings that don't match. here's an example

```
p = ['1', '0', '0', '1']
s = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Duck', 'Dog']
```

p is a pattern and what this list says is that the items in position index 0 and index 3 should match and the items in position index 1 and index 2 should match. Here we can see that 'Dog' and 'Dog' match but 'Cat' and 'Duck' do not. So the return would be

```
[['Cat', 'Duck']]
```

If for instance the string was `s = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Cat', 'Dog']` the return would be

```
[]
```

Some more examples:

```
p = ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1']
s = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Blue']
```

return would be `[['Red', 'Blue', 'Blue']]` because index 0, 1, and 4 don't match

```
p = ['1', '1', '1', '1']
s = ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Green']
```

return should be `[['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Green']]` because all indexes needed to match

```
p = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
s = ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red']
```

return would be `[]` since there is no matching required

Answer (score 1):

1. First, group the strings in `s` based on the indexes in `p`

   ```
   groups = {}

   for index, item in zip(p, s):
       groups.setdefault(index, []).append(item)
   ```
2. Now, check if all the items are the same or not, in each group, by converting the list to a set (sets will remove the duplicated items, so if the length is 1 then all are the same). If they are not, add them to the result, like this

   ```
   [items for items in groups.values() if len(set(items)) != 1]
   ```

Now, the whole program becomes like this

```
def get_unmatch(p, s):
    groups = {}
    for index, item in zip(p, s):
        groups.setdefault(index, []).append(item)
    return [items for items in groups.values() if len(set(items)) != 1]
```

And few test cases,

```
assert(get_unmatch(['1', '0', '0', '1'], ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Duck', 'Dog']) == [['Cat', 'Duck']])
assert(get_unmatch(['1', '0', '0', '1'], ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Cat', 'Dog']) == [])
assert(get_unmatch(['1', '1', '0', '0', '1'], ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Blue']) == [['Red', 'Blue', 'Blue']])
assert(get_unmatch(['1', '1', '1', '1'], ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Green']) == [['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Green']])
assert(get_unmatch(['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red']) == [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using `set`s:

```
def matcher(p, s):
    data = {}
    for k,v in zip(p,s):
        data.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

    for k,v in data.items():
        if len(set(v)) != 1:
            print v

    return
```

The function `matcher` first creates a `dict` of values which have the same index ('0' or '1'). A sample item in this `dict` would be `1 -> ['Dog', 'Dog']`. Calling `set` on the list will retain only 1 item since all list items are the same `Dog`. If they are not the same, `len(set(v))` would return a set with more than 1 item and we print this list.

#### Sample input:

```
p = ['1', '0', '0', '1']
s = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Duck', 'Dog']
print p
print s
matcher(p, s)

p = ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1']
s = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Blue']
print p
print s
matcher(p, s)


p = ['1', '1', '1', '1']
s = ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Green']
print p
print s
matcher(p, s)

p = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
s = ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red']
print p
print s
matcher(p, s)
```

#### Sample output:

```
['1', '0', '0', '1']
['Dog', 'Cat', 'Duck', 'Dog']
['Cat', 'Duck']
['1', '1', '0', '0', '1']
['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Blue']
['Red', 'Blue', 'Blue']
['1', '1', '1', '1']
['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Green']
['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Green']
['1', '2', '3', '4']
['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red']
```